# direction of vertical half-tangent (?)

Tags: derivatives

(half-tangent is the translation of "demi-tangente" from french, I don't know if it's the right term though)

As shown in the image below, the two vertical half-tangents are represented by two arrows, and I need to know the reason behind their directions (one goes up and the other down)

[Function graph and variation table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duv6x.png)

Also we have $\lim \limits_{x \to 1-}$ f '(x) = $\lim \limits_{x \to -1+}$ f '(x) = +∞

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the four cases

let $$D(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

- $\lim_{x\to a^+}D(x)=+\infty$ UP
- $\lim_{x\to a^+}D(x)=-\infty$ DOWN
- $\lim_{x\to a^-}D(x)=+\infty$ DOWN
- $\lim_{x\to a^-}D(x)=-\infty$ UP

The direction of the half-tangente depends on the function ( increasing or decreasing) and on the limit (left or right).